# How to do deferred deeplink in ios

Tags: ios, flutter

i am creating a plugin which needs deferred deeplinking and have no idea how to do this.
I found this  [link](https://innovationm.co/deferred-deep-linking-in-ios-with-universal-link/) to save link in website cookie but i think iOS 11 does not allow
i am not sure if this will work or not
please explain if anyone have done this before

Comment: Deferred deeplinking means downloading the app in that case and directly continue with the link?

Comment: yes downloading the app and receiving the deeplink in app after install